# What RPM on 2nd CPU Fan is better? Higher, lower or the same?

Tags: processor, cooling

So I've bought a SilentiumPC Fera 2 HE1224 CPU cooler for cooling my CPU and I really like it so I want to make my CPU even cooler by adding an another fan to blow the air out - on the other side of the radiator. But i do not know if I should buy the fan with more RPM, lower RPM or the same RPM as the original has. Actual Fan has 1400 rpm. Thanks for the answers.

Edit: This is how it approximately looks now. 
[image: http://www.bestpcinfo.pl/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/SilentiumPC-Fera-2-Monta%C5%BC-na-p%C5%82ycie.jpg]

Comment: It's not typically recommended to have a two fans mounted on the cooler itself due to voltage. If you are still considering, due to the voltage, you should get one with a lower RPM that way fresh air is still able to blow the old hot air without it breezing around the case.

Comment: I agree with Cfinley. Another point to consider if the fans produce even the slightest bit of vibration they will resonate if the fans are at different RPMs. Think of airplane propellers, there is a reason they get synchronized to same RPMs.

Comment: Your question has been closed because it isn't quite descriptive enough to allow others to accurately recommend products that would fit your case. If you edit your question to include more specific info about the hardware you're looking for, it can be reopened. See the [question quality guidelines](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/206/155) for more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would get the same fan that is on the cooler. You know that it will fit on the cooler and have the same performance. I would make sure that you have enough room on the other side of the cooler before purchasing the additional fan, as it look like you might have another heat sink in the way (it might not be, its just hard to tell from your picture at that angle).

It appears that [this fan](https://www.silentiumpc.com/en/sigma-pro-120-pwm/) is the same one that comes with the cooler. If you do not decide to get the same fan, I would get a fan that has the same RPM as the one on the cooler, as the fan with the lower RPM will just get in the way of the faster fan, reducing the cooling effectiveness.

Comment: Actually that picture isn't mine, it's only for illustration. And the fan that you recommended isn't the right one (it is faster), but i guess i got the catch, that I should stay on the same level. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: So what I found out is, that from the SilentiumPC I can get only the one that u posted (1600 RPM), they do not sell any 1400 RPM fan. So i want to ask, is it going to be OK or not? (if i put faster to blow the air out of the case / on the other side of the radiator) Or should I really get some other 1400 RPM fan?
EDIT: Oh I think i figured it out, I'll buy 2 of these and the one what's actually mounted there I'll put somewhere else. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @mikro45 If you still want two fans on it, I would buy two identical fans and replace the one that came with it. I was also looking at the air flow specs of the fans that they offer, and the one that comes with the cooler is the best at 55,00 CFM. The one I posted has 46,50 CFM. It might be best to contact Silentium directly and ask for another identical fan.